# How to make all model properites nullable in asp net core api

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core

I have a scenario i have a ASP Net Core API project which is used across the globe but i have to make all (INT,Long, Double, Decimal) datatypes to nullable. but why? these datatypes has already 0 value by default right? but the issue came recently that some third party call our api by passing null value to int data variable so our api crashed because it was not nullable. Hope you understand the logic why we need to do that.

> So how i will be able to do this work? in my opinion, i have two
> options.
>
> 1. make nullable data types and change all referenced code which is extremely headache.(is it a good approach to change code in all files?)
> 2. use some generic attributes or custom data validation to check the value before being assigned to the parameter value. (But i don't know how to
>    achieve this)

Expert, Please advise Can I do something like this?

```
> [CheckIIntllegaType]
> public int testId { get; set; }
```

**Second Issue**

I have models Parent so there are many nested child models so if child model is null so api is also crashing because `parent.child.property` is causing error as child is null. so is there any way that I can handle this as  generic rather then editing all reference?

Comment: You get data as JSON?

Comment: Be very, *very* careful about `0` vs `null`, they are **not** the same, `0` is a value, and can definitely be a valid value, `null` is the explicit absence of a value. It seems like you made a mistake in your original API design, if `testId` is not required, then you should have made it nullabe (`int?`) from the start, seems like that mistake came back to haunt you now

Comment: yes i get the data as json

Comment: You can have a look at `Newtonsoft.Json`. You can set validation right in DTO something like `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` or `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]`

Comment: Regarding `so api is also crashing because parent.child.property is causing error as child is null` - so if your logic expects `child` to be not `null` why don't you validate it before executing this logic?

Comment: is api will procees if i pass {testid:Null} or {testid:'Null'}

Comment: `Regarding so api is also crashing because parent.child.property` - so i will have to initialize child instance in parent model constructor right? so it will not null  if i'm not wrong.

Comment: if child is `null` but it shouldn't then you just need to return 400 bad request because request is not valid for the use case

Comment: but sometimes it optional

Comment: "these datatypes has already 0 value by default right?" `0` is a value. `null` is no value

Comment: It seems to be not possible to globally make int/decimal/float type property nullable. Maybe you can have a try to custom model binding but I think it is still very complex to custom.

Comment: @Rena exactly so can i create some data anotation model to validate the null value if it is passing to avoid error.

Comment: Hi @AbdulAleemSolutions, If you pass null value to int/decimal.. type, your whole model will receive null cause the failure of model binding. For your idea, I do not think it will work because Model validation occurs after model binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the nullable operator

```
[CheckIIntllegaType]
public int? testId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).